# How SVN server internally stores Files which have prop svn:eol-syle set

Tags: svn

Recentally I was working on setting up svn:eol-style for my project. We got success in that.
files were being checked out on linux machine, windows machines and Mac flawlessly and were being checked in perfectly.
Suddenly a question popped up in my head in which format does SVN server stores the files.
What if we want to change the operating system where we are hosting SVN server; Lets says from windows to Linux (yeah its more less likely but can happen)
What will the scenario ?

- Does SVN server saves the files native format of operating system it runs on.
- Or it just keep some nutural format.
- if it has some specific native format, what is that ? Is that configurable ?

I never been svn admin nor I will manage svn repo, still interested to know how server works at its end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends how you set `svn:eol-style`...

- **svn:eol-style="LF"**: Stored in repository as Unix line endings
- **svn:eol-style="CRLF"**: Stored in repository as Windows line endings
- **svn:eol-style="native"**: Stored in repository as Unix line endings, but when checked out on a Windows system, the line endings will be converted to Windows line endings and converted back on check in.
- **svn:eol-style not set**: No conversion is done. Stored just as user entered it.

Let your developers know about setting autoprops in their Subversion configuration file. I also have a [pre-commit hook](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/newest_svn_hooks.zip) that can enforce the use of `svn:eol-style` by preventing files from being committed unless that property is set to the correct value.